# Allocating value to variable if a condition is met in data.table

Tags: r, conditional-statements, data.table, mean

I have a big data set with the following variables

```
student_ID=c(rep("1001",8),rep("1002",3),rep("1003",11))
grades=c(NA,rep(40,2),50,60,90, 5,NA,51, rep(47,5),rep(70,5),rep(42,3))
Year=c(rep(2011,4),rep(2012,4),2011,2012,2013,rep(2011,4),rep(2012,3),rep(2013,4))
data<-data.table(student_ID,grades,Year)
setkey(data, student_ID)
```

I need to create two new variables. One for average grade by student. One for whether the average grade is <50 (1 if yes, 0 if no) for any given year.

Once this is done I will be looking at the subset at the student and year level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For creating two columns grouped by 'student_ID', we need to assign ( `:=`) the output (`mean(grades)` and the binary output) to new column names.

```
data[, c('MeanGrade', 'MeanGradelessthan50') :={tmp <- mean(grades, na.rm=TRUE)
                                  list(tmp, +(tmp < 50))}, by = student_ID]
```

If we need to summarise, instead of assigning, use `list`

```
data[, {tmp <- mean(grades, na.rm=TRUE)
     list(MeanGrade=tmp, MeanGradelessthan50 = +(tmp < 50))}, by = .(student_ID, Year)]
```

Comment: my manager just changed the parameters of my task. wants to look at whether status changes year on year (see above edits)

Comment: @MonikaSarder Can you show the expected output as it is not clear what you meant by status changes.  Is it like if one student ID say 1 have mean < 50 and the next also < 50, it is 0, if the 3rd changes from to >=50, 1?

Comment: I will be using a beckman correction model to what factors influence whether a  student (say 2014 engineering cohort)  who has <50 in 2014 will then have a <50 in 2015. Each student_ID will have multiple year rows (2010, 2011,2012 etc) and a single value (1 or 0) for their average that year. say in SQL student_id and Year would be primary key if that makes sense.

Comment: @MonikaSarder  Sorry, I don't know much about beckman correction model.

Comment: Just needs to have one assignment for each student for each year they were enrolled - whether their average grade that year was <50.say in SQL student_id and Year would be primary key if that makes sense. Whether they were <50 by Year AND student_ID.

Comment: @MonikaSarder In that case, we don't need to create columns just do `data[,  {tmp <- mean(grades, na.rm=TRUE); list(MeanGrade=tmp, MeanGradelessthan50 = +(tmp < 50))}, by = student_ID]`

Comment: @MonikaSarder Just noticed that you updated the comment.  If you have both year and student_ID as grouping variables, replace `by = .(student_ID, Year)]`